# Run python program from pip venv without system python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The answer to this question could be "You're as dumb as a wooden bowl" but I have searched a lot and haven't found a solution without installing python on other computers.

I have a python/flask web app that I need to distribute to many users. However, I can't install python on all those computers and there is no computer which everyone can access. And I cant serve the app internally from a server either. Yes, that's what I'm dealing with.

I have saved the git repo it in a network drive that everyone can access. I hoped I could run a batch file to spin the localhost server from a copied environment for the user and then use the web app.

I copied a conda environment over to the network drive and tried to use that but that gave me a *Importing the numpy c-extensions failed* error.

I tried including a pip environment (`.\env`) in the folder. So I thought any user could just activate the environment using the batch file ...

```
cd %cd%
.\env\Scripts\activate.bat
.\env\Scripts\python.exe run.py
```

but it's not working.

The `.\env\Scripts\activate` just crashes. I amended the activate.bat `set "VIRTUAL_ENV=%cd%\env"` to ensure it uses the current folder. Still crashes.

If I exclude that then `.\env\Scripts\python.exe run.py` still looks for a python installation at the path I have on my machine rather than the path I provided above.

Is there a solution to this?

*All the computers will be using Windows but may vary between Windows 7 and Windows 10. I'm doing the development from my Windows 10 computer.*

Answer (score 0):

After activating venv My below code worked:

```
(Monday) C:\Users\Resurctova\Desktop\PoraPuski\Monday>python new.py
```

Output :

```
testing
```

since the new.py has code to print testing

As Monday is my venv I activated it and executed the script.

Do not execute in Scripts folder of your venv environment

Answer (score 0):

Have you though about creating an exec file and that will save all your folders. Using a tool lik [PyInstaller](https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/). You just need to share the output exe file without installing python.